# Mounted EFS into existing directory, how to return content that was there?

Tags: linux, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, directory

Mounted **EFS** into **/var** directory, I don't see any content that used to be there.

Is there anyway to return the content?

Comment: Not a programming question; this belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux .

Answer (score 0):

If I just unmount it, it will return, so no problem:

```
umount /var
```